# Sending few commands with BLE without microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth-low-energy

I am completely new to electrical engineering, but I am trying to build a small device with three buttons circuit, each one of them would send a different command to the mobile phone via Bluetooth low energy module (I would like to use [EYSHSNZWZ Bluetooth Low Energy Module](https://www.semiconductorstore.com/cart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=70779) for its size).

So the main question, can I run this idea without any microcontroller? Can I even connect it without the microcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the smallest possible form factor or is it acceptable to start with a larger breakout board to work out your design and miniaturize from there?

SparkFun has a breakout board specific to this bluetooth module and a nice tutorial to get you started with the programming environment, getting the chip into bootloader mode and uploading your program:

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf52832-breakout-board-hookup-guide

I haven't used this specific BLE module but if you follow their instructions and run in the Arduino IDE you'll basically just be looking to set a hardware interrupt on 3 of your GPIO pins with a handler that would help debounce and queue a command to be sent by a periodic task handler.

Answer (score 5):

The module already includes a microcontroller. The website you linked to says:

> The on-chip processor has sufficient space for many applications, so a carrier board may only include sensors and a battery. The module is based on a Nordic nRF52832 chip that has an ARM Cortex-M4F, which includes 512Kbytes of flash memory and 64Kbytes of RAM.

You'll need to write some code for it in order to convert your contact closures into appropriate messages, but the only additional hardware you'll need is a power source, the switches and possibly some pullup resistors.